# Input form to clear once submitted using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a simple to do list wherein the add and delete works. My problem is, after submitting a todo, the input box won't clear.

This is my app.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState([]);
  const [toDo, setToDo] = useState("");

  const handleToDo = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setToDo(value);
  };

  const submit = () => {
    //const list = toDoList;
    const newItem = {
      id: 1 + Math.random(),
      value: toDo,
    };
    if (newItem.value && !toDoList.includes(newItem.value)) {
      toDoList.push(newItem);
      setToDoList([...toDoList]);
    }
  };

  return (
      <div className="container">
          Add an Item
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Type item here..."
            onChange={handleToDo}
          />
          <button className="add-btn btn-floating" onClick={submit}>
            <i class="material-icons"> + </i>
          </button>
          <br />
          <ul>
            ...display of todos here
          </ul>
        </div>
  );
  //}
};

export default App;
```

I'm confused as to where I should insert the useState so that the input would be reset.

Comment: Your `value` attribute of your input should be `value={toDo}`. You can then reset the state with `setToDo('')`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the input box must also be governed by the state. So the input should be like:

```
<input
   value={toDo}
   type="text"
   placeholder="Type item here..."
   onChange={handleToDo}
/>
```

Once You click on submit, reset the toDo to empty

```
const submit = () => {
//const list = toDoList;
const newItem = {
  id: 1 + Math.random(),
  value: toDo,
};
if (newItem.value && !toDoList.includes(newItem.value)) {
  toDoList.push(newItem);
  setToDoList([...toDoList]);
}
setToDo("");
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your input seems to be half-controlled. You should also give the input a value property as such:

```
<input
 type="text"
 placeholder="Type item here..."
 onChange={handleToDo}
 value={toDo}
/>
```

And now you can clear out the input when a task is submitted:

```
const submit = () => {
    //rest of the code here...
    setToDo('') //this'll clear out the value of your input
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `value` to `input` element. And after submit, set it to an empty string. So:

```
const App = () => {
  const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState([]);
  const [toDo, setToDo] = useState("");

  const handleToDo = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setToDo(value);
  };

  const submit = () => {
    //const list = toDoList;
    const newItem = {
      id: 1 + Math.random(),
      value: toDo,
    };
    if (newItem.value && !toDoList.includes(newItem.value)) {
      toDoList.push(newItem);
      setToDoList([...toDoList]);
      setToDo("");
    }
  };

  return (
      <div className="container">
          Add an Item
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            value={toDo}
            placeholder="Type item here..."
            onChange={handleToDo}
          />
          <button className="add-btn btn-floating" onClick={submit}>
            <i class="material-icons"> + </i>
          </button>
          <br />
          <ul>
            {toDoList.map((todoLi) => (
              <li>{todoLi}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
  );
  //}
};

export default App;
```

Comment: using value={toDo} instead of defaultValue={toDo} worked for me.

Comment: @Niic oh yes! so sorry

Comment: @Niic I see this intelligent condition : `newItem.value && !toDoList.includes(newItem.value)`. If you want you can add a simple beautiful validation error

Comment: @Niic did help you?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass empty string in setToDo, after all the code in your submit function setToDo("")